# Undo last executed function with jquery

Tags: jquery, undo

is there an opportunity to undo the execution of the last called function. For example I click a

```
<nav><a href="foo">...</a></nav>
```

It has an onclick-listener, something like that:

```
$(function() {
    $('nav a').on('click', function() {
        $('nav a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active');
        return false;
    });
});
```

I am looking for something with that I can undo the execution of the last function. Any suggestion? Thx!!! :)

Comment: Seems like you're missing the `#` in the `href` on your minified example.

Answer (score 13):

Use [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), i.e.

> Command objects are useful for implementing multi-level undo - 
>   if all user actions in a program are implemented as command objects,
>   the program can keep a stack of the most recently executed commands.
>   When the user wants to undo a command, the program simply pops the
>   most recent command object and executes its undo() method.

The basic JavaScript implementation can look like this:

```
function command(instance) {    
  this.command = instance;
  this.done = [];

  this.execute = function execute() {
    this.command.execute();
    this.done.push(this.command);
  };      
  this.undo = function undo() {
    var command = this.done.pop();
    command.undo();    
  };  
}
```

To test this, construct simple DOM:

```
<ul>
    <li>first</li>
</ul>
```

and define a command object, you want to use. Such an object should contain its execution logic along with additional behavior for reconstructing previous state of your DOM (in our sample case at least):

```
var appendcommand = new command({
  execute: function(){
    $('ul').append('<li>new</li>');
  },
  undo: function(){
      $('ul li:last').remove();
  }
});
```

After executing:

```
appendcommand.execute();
```

your page will change from

- first

to

- first
- new

while the execution of:

```
appendcommand.undo();
```

will transform this page to its original state:

- first

Comment: Very elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript engines do not save any previous states for you, you have to do it your self. This means that you have to keep track of the previous and current states of the objects that you want to manipulate.

In your case, you could have a list of "previously active" objects, and your "undo" would then activate the previous element based on that list.

I haven't tried the code, but you should get the idea from this. Also, check out http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp if you have trouble with arrays.

```
var undoList = new Array();

function manipulate(elem) {
    $('nav a').removeClass('active');
    $(elem).addClass('active');
    //...
}

function undo() {
    if(undoList.length > 0) {
        var elemToManipulate = undoList.pop();
        manipulate(elemToManipulate);
    }        
}

function manipulateWithUndo(elem) {
    undoList.push(elem);
    manipulate(elem);
}
```

Comment: Alright, thx. To be honest I don't know how to do that exactly. Just tried to find something in the internet, but couldn't find anything related. Can you give me a hint or a snippet?

Comment: Added a snippet as an example of the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var active=0;

    if(active==0)
    {
    //write here your code
    active=1;
    }else
    {
    //write here your "undo" code
    //example: Write your code but in reverse order: addclass().removeclass().removeclass()
    active=0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('nav a').unbind()
```

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

*- or -*

```
$('nav a').off()
```

http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 0):

```
    var clk=1; 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").on('click',function(){
        if(clk%2==1){
           $('#sidebar').addClass('active');
             $(".main").css("display", "flex");
         }else{

             $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
             $(".main").css("display", "");
        }

        clk++;
    });
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just wanted to give a simple answer. I think there are plenty of explanation regarding this quiz.